# Approach to manage SharePoint modern page from c#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm pretty new to SharePoint development but, so far, I've successfully used CSOM or Graph to interface with sites and groups. I have created team sites programmatically in c#.

I now need to programmatically change the homepage of the newly created site by customising the layout and adding existing lists and spfx web parts.

My question is: what is the preferred approach (if there is one) to create, customise the layout, and add web parts of a team site (group connected) page programmatically and reliably?

I have tried using CSOM (Graph API is in beta for page management) without success as I can't find reliable documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the best working solution for my application is to use Graph API which is (at the moment) in beta but works reliably.

With the Graph API .NET implementation is easy to retrieve and manipulate the pages of a SharePoint website.
Here is the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/api/resources/basesitepage?view=graph-rest-beta

I would add that Graph Explorer is a great tool to test how the API works before implementing the code. [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)

Answer (score -1):

The preferred approach for programmatically creating, customizing the layout, and adding web parts to a team site (group-connected) page can depend on your specific requirements and the technology stack you're comfortable with. However, Microsoft provides several options for achieving this programmatically and reliably:

SharePoint Framework (SPFx):

SharePoint Framework allows you to build client-side web parts using modern JavaScript frameworks like React, Angular, or Vue.js.
You can create custom web parts and deploy them to your SharePoint Online environment.
SPFx provides a reliable and supported way to customize SharePoint pages programmatically.
You can use SPFx to add web parts to team site pages and customize their layout as needed.
Microsoft Graph API:

Microsoft Graph API provides endpoints for managing SharePoint sites and pages programmatically.
You can use the Microsoft Graph API to create new pages, update page properties, and add web parts to pages.
This approach gives you flexibility in integrating SharePoint customization into your existing applications or workflows.
SharePoint PnP (Patterns and Practices):

SharePoint PnP provides reusable components, libraries, and guidance for SharePoint development.
You can use SharePoint PnP to automate site provisioning, page creation, and web part addition.
SharePoint PnP offers PowerShell cmdlets, C# libraries, and other tools to help streamline development tasks.